# iOS 17 customizes the keyboard, Set -inputview and -inputAccessoryview at the same time, inputView cannot be displayed

Tags: swift, ios17

iOS 17 customizes the keyboard, Set -inputview and -inputAccessoryview at the same time, inputView cannot be displayed, Below is the code for custom input view。

```
class CustomerInputView: UIView {

    // custom -inputView
    private var _inputView: UIView? = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 300))
    public override var inputView: UIView? {
        set {
            _inputView = newValue
        }
        get {
            _inputView
        }
    }
    
    // custom -inputAccessoryView
    private var _inputAccessoryView: UIView? = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 45))
    public override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        _inputAccessoryView
    }
}
```